# Running Xamarin Ui tests cross-platform

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I'm running my xamarin ui tests on appcenter and when I ran on ios device it also running the android tests and they fail...
I have tests for both of the platform like this :

how can I not run the android tests while I'm running ios tests on ios device ?
and please don't answer to comment the test fixture: //[TestFixture(Platform.Andriod)]

Answer (score 0):

I added Categories in the TestFixture attribute :
[image]

When I'm running iOS I Exclude Android and when I'm running Android I exclude iOS Like this :
[image]